# Enable All Languages Font in an Application

Tags: android, fonts, webview

My application is a simple web view type of app. It just loads a website in one page but I'm having a font issue where on some devices some languages are not supported, is there any solution for this situation?

My code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView web1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web1.loadUrl("http://dcs-dof.gujarat.gov.in/live-info.htm");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First please make sure the `charset` attribute is correctly set in HTTP header or the `meta` field of the HTML page.
2. Besides, and the displaying may also depend on the fonts pre-loaded on the specific devices. Although by default most languages are supported in Android AOSP, but as far as I known some manufacturers will remove some characters/languages just in order to save up the disk spaces.

To tackle #2, A tricky way is to install/copy the fonts manually to your device under `/system/fonts`.